# Private boolean cannot recognize return in "if statement"

Tags: java, if-statement, boolean, private

My code:

```
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

public class Controller {
    public Label keno;
    public Label loto;
    public Random rd = new Random();

    public void click(ActionEvent actionEvent) {

        String pom = "";
        int[] ken = zrebuj(10, 80);
        pom = Arrays.toString(ken);
        pom = pom.substring(1, pom.length() - 1);
        keno.setText(pom);


        ken = zrebuj(5, 35);
        pom = Arrays.toString(ken);
        pom = pom.substring(1, pom.length() - 1);
        loto.setText(pom);
    }

    private int[] zrebuj(int pocet, int max) {

        int[] cisla = new int[pocet];

        for (int i = 0; i < cisla.length; i++) {
            int tah = rd.nextInt(max) + 1;

            if (jeTam(cisla, tah)==false) {
                cisla[i] = tah;
            }
            else i--;
        }
        Arrays.sort(cisla);
        return cisla;
    }

    private boolean jeTam(int[] cisla, int tah) {

        for (int i = 0; i < cisla.length; i++) {

            if (cisla[i] == tah) {
                return true;
            }
            else return false;
        }

    }
}
```

My problem is, that when I start program, it crashes and it says: **"Missing return statement"** at the private boolean, even thought it´s right there in if statement.

*Could you help me please? Thanks!*

*Also, if you have any tips to make it better, just tell me in the coments ;)

Comment: What does the method return if `cisla.length == 0`?

Comment: @AndyTurner it´s never 0

Comment: @DownFury the compiler does not know that. The error you're getting is a compiler error, not during runtime.

Comment: @f1sh but it´s set that pocet is 10 and 5 and that equals cislo

Comment: @DownFury to reiterate: *the compiler does not know that*. The compiler is pretty dumb (or should I say, simple), in many ways: the only time it considers a `for` loop always to execute is if the condition is a constant expression which evaluates to true, e.g. `true`.

Comment: @AndyTurner ok ty <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are seeing is valid because :

```
private boolean jeTam(int[] cisla, int tah) {

    for (int i = 0; i < cisla.length; i++) {

        if (cisla[i] == tah) {
            return true;
        }
        else return false;
    }
  // <---- NO RETURN STATEMENT
}
```

You have not supplied a return value when the for loop ends.
Meaning, your for loop runs and on it's first run either returns false or true (based on your logic).

But the compiler looks at your code and sees that there is a missing return statement at the end of the method.

```
private boolean jeTam(int[] cisla, int tah) {

    for (int i = 0; i < cisla.length; i++) {

        if (cisla[i] == tah) {
            return true;
        }
        else return false;
    }

   return false //For Example

}
```

Comment: However, it's worth pointing out that the `return false` in the loop is probably not intended - this loop will always return on the first iteration if the array is non-empty.

Comment: @tomerpacific so it always need a return statement except for return in loop etc. ?

Comment: @DownFury whenever you state in your function signature that you are returning a value, then for each logical flow, that return value must occur. If my answer helped you, please mark it as such.